# Using RDP but audio doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Tags: windows, audio, rdp

- Host: Windows 11 Pro
- Client: Windows 10

I'm not able to listen any audio on client from host when I'm in a RDP session

- Rebooted windows audio services
- Allowed "Allow audio and video playback" on Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, Remote Desktop Session Host, Device and Resource Redirection
- Checked "Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector" service is active
- Rebooted host machine

Event logs on "TerminalServices-MediaRedirection" and "TerminalServices-RdpSoundDriver" are empty